# CakePHP: Can belongs to be NULL or nothing

Tags: cakephp

I currently have two tables

> A with fields [id,title, **b_id**]
>   B with fields [id,url]

Can  **b_id** be NOTHING? Let's say a certain record A used to have a B but now i want to edit A and remove the value **b_id** and just leave that record with a valid id and a title.

How do i go about this? Is this even allowed in cakephp or I am simply using the wrong association type.

Comment: [Nullable Behavior](https://github.com/robwilkerson/CakePHP-NullableBehavior)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can b_id be NOTHING?

That's up to you and your validation rules, and depends on your application and database logic. If `b_id` (please use real names) is logically optional, there is nothing in the framework fundamentally preventing it from being null.